# sizing DOM elements with HTML & CSS

Tags: css, html

When creating a `<header>` within a HTML document is there a standard way of setting the size of the `<header>` tag in CSS?  For example, Stack Overflow's header is set at 31px, and many other sites use values such as 107px or 117px sizes that are not even numbers.  Is there a method behind determining these heights?

Comment: Might want to try this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com. It isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty much decided by how tall you actually want the header to be. This might be especially important, say, if you have floating elements, but the desired height of the header is usually the deciding factor in setting its height =)